# PHP Check if date falls within certain hour

Tags: php, date, datetime

Given a DateTime Object how can I check if the hour falls under a certain range?

```
$local_time = new DateTime();

//time is after 06:00:00 am
if (date('H', $local_time) >= 6) {

echo "After 6am";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime objects are comparible:

```
$local_time = new DateTime();
$six_am     = new DateTime('6am');

//time is after 06:00:00 am
if ($local_time  > $six_am) {

   echo "After 6am";

}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/710945)

Note: this only works if the comparison is being done on the same day. It's gets more complex if you plan on crossing dates.

Comment: How can this be modified so $six_am isnt a new datetime object but taken from the time of object $local_time?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: Suppose I was given a date passed in the program and I wanted to see if its time is over 6am? If this isn't relevant to the question Im sorry

Comment: Just pass it as a parameter to the datetime object whose time you want to change. `$local_time = new DateTime($yourDateTimeVariable);` Just make sure it is in a [standard format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).